# Using UINavigationController for inner UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

What I have an iphone screen with a main UIView which has another UIView inside it with the size of 280x280 which has a tableview inside it. What I want is that when a user selects any row of that table inside that inner UIView, it pushes the user to another 280x280 UIView, so basically the main view is going to be fixed but only the inner view changes. What's the concept that can make this happen ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that user994813 wants to say this:

- A UINavigationController controls the total screen. So, only pushing
  and popping a 280x280 field is not possible.
- The best way to achieve this would be to let a UITableViewController
  be the controller of the main view. Use this as delegate and datasource
  for your 280x280 tableview.
- When a user selects a row, use a transition to let the tableview
  disappear and the other 280x280 view appear. In other words, I fear
  that you have to do this manually, although it's not very hard.
- If you need a NavigationBar, create it manually in interfaceBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create two 280*280 view one for your tableview and another for other(push view) and whenever you select table row you need to hidden true first view and hidden false second view(pushview).

Comment: I'm using UINavigationController, can you please explain a bit more ? thank you.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think what you're suggesting is what I'm looking for, because I'm trying to navigate through several inner views while my main view is fixed.